# How can I get number of symbol in string

Tags: javascript

Hello I have this function

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(
    searchInput, 
    'keydown', 
    (e) => {
        console.log('num=>',e.num)
```

As you see I am trying to get number of e symbol in all string in this handler

I can get it by console.log('num=>',searchInput.value.length) But how I can get the keyCode of last character in value when i keydown this e

Comment: are you talking about getting the keyCode?. You can do e.keyCode, e.key or e.which

Comment: after formatting your code, we see some `)` are missing !`? Share **entire portion of code** please.

Comment: not keyCode but the position in the all string of this e character

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.fromCharCode(e.which || e.keyCode)`, this would give you the character representation of the key press eg. if you press 1 it would be '1' (also `e.key`).

If you want the actual key code (for example the key `1` would be `49`)  then `e.which` or `e.keyCode` (depending on the browser)